# Unable to read system variables in spring boot in MacOS. Have not tried it in any other OS. Do I need to to do anything else other than the following?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, macos, secret-key

```html
Spring version
<version>2.7.13-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I am trying to access the system env variables directly in the application.properties file.

I do not want to use any external configuration. The reason is I am trying to access the same environment variables that other services are using which is developed in other languages. Due to this reason, I am bound to use the same key name and access it from my spring project. External configuration would mean one more copy of the same variables.

I am working on mac and added the variables in both profile

```html
~/.zprofile
export LOCAL_DB_USERNAME="root"
```

```html
~/.bash_profile

export LOCAL_DB_USERNAME="root"
```

and used it in my application.properties

```html
spring.datasource.username=${LOCAL_DB_USERNAME}
```

It is not accessing the variable and the database is not connected.
Moreover, when I am trying to access it in a Java class using

```html
class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService

logger.info(environment.getProperty("LOCAL_DB_USERNAME"));
```

It is giving null